# how to generate dynamic web page through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

```js
  <font style="color:#03C">Select PF Office State</font> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <select name="state" id="state" onchange="generate_table();">
      <option value="select" >-- Select a State --</option>
            
      <!--<option value="AN">ANDAMAN AND NICOBAR ISLANDS</option>-->
      <option value="WB">ANDAMAN AND NICOBAR ISLANDS</option>
      <option value="AP">ANDHRA PRADESH</option>

            
      <!--<option value="AR">ARUNACHAL PRADESH</option>-->
      <option value="AS">ARUNACHAL PRADESH</option>      
      <option value="AS">ASSAM</option>
            
      <option value="BH">BIHAR</option>
            
      <!--<option value="CH">CHANDIGARH</option>-->
      <option value="PB">CHANDIGARH</option>     
      <option value="CG">CHATTISGARH</option>
            
      <option value="DN">DADRA AND NAGAR HAVELI</option>

            
      <option value="DD">DAMAN AND DIU</option>
            
      <option value="DL">DELHI</option>
            
      <option value="GA">GOA</option>
            
      <option value="GJ">GUJARAT</option>
            
      <option value="HR">HARYANA</option>
            
      <option value="HP">HIMACHAL PRADESH</option>

            
      <option value="JK">JAMMU AND KASHMIR</option>
            
      <option value="JR">JHARKHAND</option>
            
      <option value="KN">KARNATAKA</option>
            
      <option value="KL">KERALA</option>
            
      <!--<option value="LD">LAKSHADWEEP</option>-->
      <!--<option value="WB">LAKSHADWEEP</option>-->
      <option value="TN">LAKSHADWEEP</option>
            
      <option value="MP">MADHYA PRADESH</option>

            
      <option value="MH">MAHARASHTRA</option>
            
      <!--<option value="MN">MANIPUR</option>
            
      <option value="MG">MEGHALAYA</option>
            
      <option value="MZ">MIZORAM</option>
            
      <option value="NL">NAGALAND</option>-->
      <option value="AS">MANIPUR</option>
            
      <option value="AS">MEGHALAYA</option>
            
      <option value="AS">MIZORAM</option>
            
      <option value="AS">NAGALAND</option>
      
      <option value="OR">ORISSA</option>

            
      <!--<option value="PN">PONDICHERRY</option>-->
      <option value="TN">PONDICHERRY</option>
      <option value="PB">PUNJAB</option>
            
      <option value="RJ">RAJASTHAN</option>
            
      <!--<option value="SK">SIKKIM</option>-->
      <option value="AS">SIKKIM</option>     
      <option value="TN">TAMIL NADU</option>
            
     <option value="TS">TELANGANA</option>
   <option value="AS">TRIPURA</option>
            
      <option value="UP">UTTAR PRADESH</option>
            
      <option value="UC">UTTARAKHAND</option>
            
      <option value="WB">WEST BENGAL</option>
</select>
  </p>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>



<div id="myDiv">

</div>
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function generate_table()
{
 if(document.getElementById('state').value == "Select")
 {
  alert('Please select a state');
  return;
 }
 var state = document.getElementById('state').value;
 document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = '<img src = "http://epfoservices.in/epfo/member_balance/images/preloader_bill.gif" style = "padding-bottom:600px; padding-left:300px;">';
 var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
 XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
 XMLHttpRequestObject = new
 ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 
 if(XMLHttpRequestObject)
 {
  var url="http://epfoservices.in/epfo/member_balance/table.php?state="+state ;
  XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", url);
  XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
  if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 &&
  XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200)
  {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
  }
  }
  XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);
 }
}

function MM_win5() { //v2.0
   //return eval(jsStr)
   var w = 650; // set the width of pop-up
   var h = 500; // set the height of pop-up
   var l = Math.floor((screen.width-w)/7);
   var t = Math.floor((screen.height-h)/2);
   //window.open(jsStr+"?identifier="+str,"pop","width=" + w + ",height=" + h + ",top=" + t + ",left=" + l);
   window.open("office_list.php", "pop", 'width=650,height=500,scrollbars=yes, top=' + t + ',left=' + l);
}
</script>
```

table not loading from http://epfoservices.in/epfo/member_balance/table.php?state= but image loading please help anyone table.php? state code In two digits letter

and the list of offices i want loan by adding state code to tablephp file

manually i can get results by placing state code to that php url

example: http://epfoservices.in/epfo/member_balance/table.php?state=up

Comment: So where is the code for `table.php`

Comment: at this location http://epfoservices.in/epfo/member_balance/table.php

Comment: But we cannot see it there. Add it to your question

Comment: Actually, it is located on 3rd party server . so can we send request from the browser?

Comment: i just knew that cross domain calls not allowed in jquery and ajax